# Cómo hacer un array bidimencional enfocado en Notas y sacar aprobados/desaprobados en Java?

Tags: java

Suponga un array con 20 alumnos que tienen 5 notas de 0 a 20. Escribir un programa que calcule el promedio de aprobados y el promedio de los suspensos e indique la cantidad de aprobados y suspensos.

esto es lo que tengo por el momento:
Lo cuál me encuentro búscando es cómo puedo realizar una validación/conteo de alguna manera que me pueda decir cuántos Alumnos aprobaron. Ahí en el código solamente utilicé 5 Almunos, para así no digitar demasiado para saber si funcionaba.

```
public class Ejercicio1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String alumnos[] = new String [5];  
         int notas[][] = new int [5][5];
         int notasFinales[] = new int[5];
         
         System.out.println("**Ingrese información de los Alumnos**");
         System.out.println("");
         
         //Nombre del Alumno
         for(int i = 0; i < alumnos.length; i++) {
             System.out.print("Ingrese nombre del Alumno: ");
             alumnos[i] = keyboard.next();
             
             //Nota del Alumno
             for(int j = 0; j < notas.length; j++) {
                 System.out.print("Ingrese la nota del Alumno " + alumnos[i] + ": ");
                 notas[i][j] = keyboard.nextInt();
             }
             System.out.println("");
             System.out.println("**Ingrese información del siguiente Alumno**");
             System.out.println("");
         }
         
        for(int i = 0; i < notasFinales.length; i++ ) {
            int sumaNotas = 0;
                for(int j = 0; j < notas[i].length; j++) {
                    sumaNotas = sumaNotas + notas[i][j];
        }
                notasFinales[i] = sumaNotas/5;
              
         }
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Las notas de los Alumnos son: ");
            for(int i = 0; i < notasFinales.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("La nota final del Alumno "+alumnos[i]+ " es: "+notasFinales[i]);
            }
          
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta explicando cual es el problema para facilitar que podamos ayudarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamente tu ejercicio ya está resuelto, sólo tienes que agregar un par de líneas de código después de hallar el promedio `notasFinales[i] = sumaNotas/5;` con la condición

```
if(notasFinales[i]>11){
    //sumas la cantidad de alumnos aprobados
    //los alumnos desaprobados será el complemento de cantidad de alumnos menos aprobados
}
```

Una vez ya tengas la cantidad de alumnos aprobados el porcentaje es: 100*(aprobados/cantidadTotal).

**Te dejaré una solución alternativa**
Dado que java es un lenguaje que soporta la Programación Orientada a objetos [POO](https://asociacionaepi.es/programacion-orientada-a-objetos-en-java/) plantearé la solución creando una clase `Alumno` con el nombre y las notas de los alumnos y en otra clase crear el arreglo de alumnos.

**Creamos la clase Alumno**

```
public class Alumno {
    private String nombre;
    private int[]notas;
    private boolean aprobado;

    public Alumno(String nombre, int[] notas) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.notas = notas; 
        promedioNotas();
    }
   
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public boolean isAprobado() {
        return aprobado;
    }    
       
    public final void promedioNotas(){
        int suma=0;
        double promedio;
        for(int i=0;i<notas.length;i++){
            suma=suma+notas[i];
        } 
        promedio=(double)suma/notas.length;
        //condicion: si promedio es mayor que 11, aprobado es true, sino false
        //es la forma abreviada de hacer la condición
        aprobado=(promedio >= 11);               
    }
   
    @Override
    public String toString() {        
        if(aprobado){
            return "Alumno{" + "nombre=" + nombre + ", Aprobado" + '}';
        }
        else
            return "Alumno{" + "nombre=" + nombre + ", Desaprobado" + '}'; 
    }
}
```

**Creamos una clase prueba con el método main**

```
public class pruebaNotas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Alumno listaAlumnos[]= new Alumno[3];        
        String nombre;
        int notasFinales[] = new int[5];
        for(int i=0;i<listaAlumnos.length;i++){
            System.out.println("\t Datos del Alumno "+(i+1));
            System.out.print("Ingrese nombre del alumno:");
            nombre=keyboard.nextLine();
            //Leemos las 5 notas para alumno
            for(int j=0;j<notasFinales.length;j++){
                System.out.print("Ingrese la nota "+(j+1)+": ");
                notasFinales[j]=keyboard.nextInt();
            }
            //limpiamos el buffer de entrada Scanner despues de leer enteros
            keyboard.nextLine(); 
            //agregamos el el nombre y notas al arreglo de alumnos
            listaAlumnos[i]=new Alumno(nombre, notasFinales);
        }
        
        int canAprobados=0;
        double porcentajeAprobados;
        
        //un foreach para recorrer nuestro arreglo y mostrar cada elemento        
        for (Alumno listaAlumno : listaAlumnos) {
            System.out.println(listaAlumno.toString());
            if (listaAlumno.isAprobado()) {
                canAprobados++;
            }            
        }
        //Hacemos un casting a canAprobados ( si no sabes porque tarea para la casa)  
        porcentajeAprobados=((double)canAprobados/listaAlumnos.length)*100;
        
        //Mostramos la cantidad de aprobados y desaprobados
        System.out.println("Cantidad de alumnos aprobados:"+canAprobados);
        System.out.println("Cantida de alumnos desaprobados: "+(listaAlumnos.length-canAprobados));
        System.out.println("Porcentaje de alumnos aprobados: "+porcentajeAprobados);
        System.out.println("Porcentaje de alumnos desaprobados: "+(100-porcentajeAprobados));
    }
```

Como puedes observar, he creado un arreglo de 3 alumnos para hacer una prueba rápida, si quieres más alumnos sólo cambiarías el 3 por el número que quieras sin tocar ninguna linea del código porque no dependen de la cantidad, en su lugar estoy usando el método `length` que tiene cada arreglo, en cambio en tu código si quieres probar con 20 alumnos tienes que cambiar varias lineas de código.

Comment: ¡Muchisimas gracias! Me ayudó bastante. :)